Шрифт отображается на сайте, но не подключается жирность
Я пытаюсь подключить шрифты на сайт. В девтулс, если навестись на текст, там стоит правильный шрифт - Inter. Но жирность не добавляется.

Пробовала вставлять ссылку из гугл фонс на прямую в head, не работает.
Меняла пути, тоже не работает.
В папке network вроде все подгружается (там показываются зеленые и
синие полоски).  
В консоли ошибок нет.
Также скачивала шрифты с другого сайта, все равно не сработало...

Если кто знает что делать, буду очень благодарна за помощь!
ссылка на гитхаб

Приведите ваш html и css код прямо в вопросе.

У вас url не правильный к файлам - url('./assets/fonts/#{$url}.woff2') format('woff2'). Вложенность больше на один уровень вроде, должно быть - url('../../assets/fonts/#{$url}.woff2') format('woff2')

@чистов_n там у неё прикол во вложенности, сюда она не сможет загрузить структуру. Там капец цепочка подключений у неё))

Ещё что я заметил, вы все mixin-ы и css файлы подключили к main.scss, но в head я не увидел подключения этого самого main.css в head.html

Спасибо за вашу помощь! У меня main.scss подключен к main.js. Остальные миксины нормально подключаются и работают...
Но я все же попробовала подключить шрифты в head, мне показало ошибку [plugin:vite:css] [sass] Error: Undefined mixin. Тогда я импортировала в base/fonts.scss файл с миксином, ошибка пропала, но жирность шрифтов так и не отображается.
Да, путь я меняла на ../../ , все равно не работает...
